# Why does typescript allow an inherited method to incompletely implement an interface?

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Consider this code:

```
type AB = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

type B = {
    b: string;
}

interface I {
    foo(x: B): void;
}

class Superclass {
    foo(x: AB): void {
        // access x.a here
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass implements I {
}
```

Class "Superclass" expects an argument that has field "a", the interface does not care about it. In class "Subclass", I would expect a compiler error since the inherited method does not cover all argument values declared in the interface -- but no such error occurs.

Why does the type checker consider this to be okay? If I create an instance of the "Subclass", pass it as an "I", then call the method with a "B", then the implementation in the "Superclass" will crash when it tries to access field "a".

If I implement the method like this in the "Subclass":

```
foo(x: B): void {
    super.foo(x);
}
```

Then I get the error I expect in the super call. (Obviously, if this last method declares its parameter to be of type AB, then it works because it resolves the conflict, but that's not what I'm asking about).